# Remove bubble count from multiple select menu

Tags: html, jquery-mobile, select

When using a selection menu with the option for multiple select, jQuery Mobile displays the number option chosen - i.e. bubble count.

```
<select name="locationlist" id="locationlist" multiple="multiple"  data-close-btn="none" data-native-menu="false" data-corners="false" class="required">
    <option>Select Location</option>
    <option value="Rajajinagar">Rajajinagar</option>
    <option value="Vijayanagar">Vijayanagar</option>
    <option value="Hebbal">Hebbal</option>
    <option value="Baneswadi">Baneswadi</option>
    <option value="Mathikere">Mathikere</option>
    <option value="Yeshwanthpur">Yeshwanthpur</option>                          
 </select>
```

How to remove the bubble count from select menu for multiple select?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no option to control count bubble in custom selectmenu, however, you can just hide it using CSS.

Edit: You need to use `!important` to force override `display`, as jQM adds an inline style `display: inline`.

```css
.ui-select span.ui-li-count {
   display: none !important;
}
```

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/kkf23ebL/)**